# Why does ServiceStack throw "Sequence contains more than one matching element"?

Tags: servicestack

I have been experimenting with a fairly simple ServiceStack service, and started getting a System.InvalidOperationException ("Sequence contains more than one matching element") when accessing the metadata URL (/xml/metadata?op=Foo, /json/metadata?op=Foo, etc.) for a particular DTO.

The DTO is:

```
[DataContract]
[Route("/foo/{Id}", "PUT")]
public class Foo : IReturn<Foo>, IHasId
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Foo() {}
}
```

And the service is:

```
public class FooService : Service
{
    private static readonly List<Foo> items = new List<Foo>
    {
        new Foo { Id = 1, Name = "Foo" },
        new Foo { Id = 2, Name = "Bar" }
    };

    public virtual object Put(Foo request)
    {
        var itemToUpdate = items.Find(p => request.Id == p.Id);

        if (itemToUpdate == null)
            throw new HttpError(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound,
                new ArgumentException(String.Format("{0} with Id {1} does not exist.", typeof(Foo).Name, request.Id)));

        itemToUpdate.PopulateWith(request);

        return request;
    }
}
```

I've commented out all other DTOs and services to try to isolate this. It appears to be coming from the ProcessOperations call in ServiceStack's [BaseMetadataHandler.cs](http://servicestack.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Common/ServiceStack.Common/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints/Metadata/BaseMetadataHandler.cs), specifically the following:

```
var operationType = allTypes.Single(x => x.Name == operationName);
```

I'm just not sure why there would be duplicate operations here (multiple with the same Name). Any ideas?

Comment: I can't recreate this with v3.9.33 and the classes you provided.

Comment: I'm on 3.9.32; let me upgrade and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to have been an issue with ServiceStack prior to 3.9.33. Once I upgraded, the issue went away.